# Can @future be called in constructor of a class

Tags: future, asynchronous, constructor

Trailhead Link - [https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/asynchronous_apex/async_apex_future_methods#:~:text=Future%20methods%20won't%20necessarily,same%20order%20they%20are%20called.&text=Future%20methods%20can't%20be,method%20from%20a%20future%20method](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/asynchronous_apex/async_apex_future_methods#:%7E:text=Future%20methods%20won%27t%20necessarily,same%20order%20they%20are%20called.&text=Future%20methods%20can%27t%20be,method%20from%20a%20future%20method).

[image]

**Why we cannot call Future from a constructor?**

Answer (score 2):

There are three things:-

1. You want to invoke future method from vf page from constructor of controller class

> You cannot not call this, You will get an error.

2. You want to invoke future method from Visualforce page not from constructor but via action attribute

> You can do this

```
public with sharing class sampleClass {
  @future
  public static void futureSampleMethod() {
    system.debug('futureSampleMethod ');
  }
}
```

and in Vf page

```
<apex:page controller="sampleClass" action="{!futureSampleMethod}">
 </apex:page>
```

Note:-

> The action method invoked when this page is requested by the server.
> Use expression language to reference an action method. For example,
> action="{!doAction}" references the doAction() method in the
> controller. If an action isn’t specified, the page loads as usual. If
> the action method returns null, the page simply refreshes.
>
> This method is called before the page is rendered, and allows you to
> optionally redirect the user to another page.
>
> Important: This action should not be used for initialization or DML.

3. You want to invoke future method from any other class which is not part of visualforce page

> You can do this

```
public with sharing class sampleClass {
    public sampleClass() {
        futureSampleMethod();
    }
    @future
    public static void futureSampleMethod() {
        system.debug('futureSampleMethod ');
    }
}
```

and you can call it from any another class:-

```
new sampleClass();
```